# Why simplyxml does not load files from aside?

Tags: php, xml

I need to parse xml file from [this link](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml).

Doing it with `$XML = simplexml_load_file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");` `var_dump($XML)` says `false`.

What could be its reason?

P.S. I've got 2 servers and on first one all is ok with the same code? Where should I look forward to solve this?

Comment: Allow your second server to allow origins outside of your IP.

Comment: it could be the only reason? mb smth in .htaccess?

Comment: You can do that in your .htaccess file, yes.

Comment: and what should be there?)

Comment: Something you could try is putting `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');` at the top of your script.

Comment: Although high level English is not expected here, following a [minimal set of the spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is gladly welcomed.